# AVD: Is there an inspector?

Tags: android, html, ios, css, eclipse

My purpose is to emulate samsung galaxy s3 and Samsung Galaxy Tablet and use their respective internet browsers to test how each device renders a webpage.To work the code more efficiently I'll need to have an inspector, **similar to the one Apple offers in the Safari browser integrated with the iOS simulator**).

Is there any plugin that enables the user to use a console and inspect the website from the AVD browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this amazing tool: **Google Chrome Canary**.  It was exactly what I needed. I can use the chrome console to **inspect** any element I want and also **emulate** a wide variety of devices. [Here is how to](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation) .I strongly recommend it to any user!.